# Run a C# method in separate Task to avoid delay

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I am working on a C# application. I have a method which runs at the start of the application, this method takes sometime due to which there is delay in application start. To overcome this i want to run that method in a separate task/thread, so that my application gets started and this method continues to run on separate thread.

Current implementation of my method is:

```
public void Start()
{
    ManagementObjectCollection ManObjReturn;
    ManagementObjectSearcher ManObjSearch;
    ManObjSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ClassGuid=\"{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\"");
    ManObjReturn = ManObjSearch.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject ManObj in ManObjReturn)
    {
        string name = ManObj["Name"].ToString();
        int i = name.LastIndexOf('(');

        string port = name.Substring(i + 1, name.Length - i - 2);
        string man = ManObj["Manufacturer"].ToString();

        for (int x = 0; x < allComPorts.Count; x++)
        {
            if (string.Equals(man, "FTDI") && string.Equals(port, UsbState.allComPorts[x]))
            {
                FtdiDevice ftdiDevice = new FtdiDevice() { ComPortName = allComPorts[x] };
                existingFtdiPorts.Add(ftdiDevice);
                OnDeviceAttached(this, new FtdiDeviceEventArgs() { ftdiDevice = ftdiDevice });
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    BackgroundWorker bgwUsbDeviceDetector = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgwUsbDeviceDetector.DoWork += UsbDeviceDetection;
    bgwUsbDeviceDetector.RunWorkerAsync();
    bgwUsbDeviceDetector.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgwUsbDeviceDetector.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}
```

After searching on the google, what i get is that we can use **Task.Run** for running on the separate task/thread.

Now my update code is:

```
public void Start()
{
    Task.Run(() => (
        ManagementObjectCollection ManObjReturn;
        ManagementObjectSearcher ManObjSearch;
        ManObjSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ClassGuid=\"{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\"");
        ManObjReturn = ManObjSearch.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject ManObj in ManObjReturn)
        {
            string name = ManObj["Name"].ToString();
            int i = name.LastIndexOf('(');

            string port = name.Substring(i + 1, name.Length - i - 2);
            string man = ManObj["Manufacturer"].ToString();

            for (int x = 0; x < allComPorts.Count; x++)
            {

                if (string.Equals(man, "FTDI") && string.Equals(port, UsbState.allComPorts[x]))
                {
                    FtdiDevice ftdiDevice = new FtdiDevice() { ComPortName = allComPorts[x] };
                    existingFtdiPorts.Add(ftdiDevice);
                    OnDeviceAttached(this, new FtdiDeviceEventArgs() { ftdiDevice = ftdiDevice });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        BackgroundWorker bgwUsbDeviceDetector = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgwUsbDeviceDetector.DoWork += UsbDeviceDetection;
        bgwUsbDeviceDetector.RunWorkerAsync();
        bgwUsbDeviceDetector.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgwUsbDeviceDetector.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    )
}
```

But this does not work and i get the error **ManagementObjectCollection is a type which is not valid in the given context**

Can anybody help me ? I know i am missing something really simple regarding Task and how to use them, but any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Where are you pulling `() => (` from? It should be a curly brace on the right of the lambda arrow.

Comment: After you fix the typo remove the BackgroundWorker. You *already* run something in the background, you don't need the BGW at all. Any events progress events it raises would be raised in the tasks' backround thread which means they can't update the UI. Whatever `UsbDeviceDetection` does, can be called directly at this point

Comment: oh, quite a silly mistake by me, btw thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I ll check if it increase the application performance.

Comment: Instead of the used of Task.Run, i think you could use the Async Await Pattern. If i remember check the version of your c# first. Has to be at least version 5 - i am no sure - to use it. So wirte your code inside a method. Something like: 'public async Task<type> MyMethodAsync() { code...}. Don´t forget to put a await keyword inside of it. Or  return something like: 'return await Task.Run(() => yourReturnType; )'

Comment: I think i can not use Async await in this case, as i do not have any operation to await @BerBar

Comment: That is why i told you above to use in your method return in case that you can pass a 'await' keyword: return await Task.Run(() => yourReturnType; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (just to you base on)

```
 public async Task<yourType> MyMethod() 
 {
    ...your code...
    return await Task.Run(()=> yourType.-any extension method if you need it-;)
 }
```